# Vue-Router меняет параметры при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Объясняю суть вопроса. Есть spa приложение на vue, использующее vuex и vue-router. И с работой динамических маршрутов роутера возникла проблема. При переходе по ссылке router-link вида /selection/:id отлично работает переход на страницу. Если же после успешного перехода на страницу обновить страницу, происходит следующее:
меняется тип параметра маршрута с Number на String, что влечет за собой множество проблем. Прилагаю скриншоты.

Маршрут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка на страницу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Свойства компонента и роутера после перехода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как видно свойство компонента id имеет тип Number.
Теперь обновляем страницу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

свойство компонента id меняет тип на String, а консоль орошается кровью:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу обратить внимание на:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Это как раз то свойство, которое меняется после обновления.

Делаю все по документации, не могу понять в чем проблема. Прошу помощи срочно!!!

Comment: Смог отчасти решить проблему возвращая в роутах результат функции:       return{id: Number(route.params.id)} . Теперь можно использовать свойство в компоненте. Но сам параметр маршрута все еще меняет тип на строчный после перезагрузки. И страница грузится неправильно из-за этого и ошибки остались.

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблема выпадающих ошибок была в том, что скрипты загружались не по абсолютному пути, а по относительному. Поменяв путь на абсолютный проблема решилась, но vue-router не перестал менять тип параметра)

Answer (score 0):

Маршрут:

```
{
    path: 'selection/:id',
    name: 'selection-page',
    props: (route) => ({ id: Number(route.params.id) })
    component: SelectionPage
}
```

Comment: Делал так, не помогло)